# Will npm update use npm cache?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-update, npm-cache

My understanding is that.
Assume I have a package.json file with

```
"bunyan": "^1.8.9"
```

I have installed this and it will be in my npm cache.

The latest version(in the given range) of bunyan is "^1.8.12"

If I run

```
npm update
```

Will it install latest version "1.8.12" regardless of the npm cache (and update package-lock.json file)?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: @jonrsharpe
 In my cache, I already have latest version. npm cache clean --force taking forever...so couldn't test completely

Comment: You don't need to manage the cache manually: just leave it alone and npm will do what you think it should and will satisfy the rules in the `package.json`. Side-note: if you run `npm ci`, it will only read `pacakge-lock.json`.

Answer (score 0):

If version `1.8.12` satisfies `1.8.9`, **yes** it will, otherwise, no.